# how to delete a 2D matrix row if first element of the row is 0 without using numpy in python

Tags: python, matrix

For example:

```py
    a = [[0 0 0 ] [1 2 3] [1 2 1] [3 2 1] [2 0 1] [0 1 3]]
```

after deleting I want to obtain:

```py
   a=[[1 2 3] [1 2 1] [3 2 1] [2 0 1]]
```

I want to only delete the row that has 0 as the 1st element.

Thank you,

Comment: I am assuming a is a list of lists...

Comment: Please share any code or attempt that you have tried and the errors or unexpected behavior that you find. In this community, we ask on specific errors. Please refer to [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension.  The 0 is already a boolean.

```
[r for r in a if r[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    if not row[0]:
        del a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension in the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

a = [x for x in a if x[0] != 0]